# In an input layer, what is the difference between input_dim and the number of nodes on the input layer?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, keras-layer

Keras code for reference. Each of my input instances is a 200 dimensional vector, and I'd like the number of nodes on the input layer to be equal to 200. What does the "100" represent in the input dense layer?

```
model = Sequential([
        Dense(100, input_dim=200),
        Activation('sigmoid'),
        Dense(150),
        Activation('sigmoid'),
        Dense(50),
        Activation('softmax'),
    ])
```

Answer (score 1):

'100' represents the number of nodes in the first hidden layer of your network.